# classpath does not match in build.gradle

Tags: flutter

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle11645302661581564201.bin offset 628139 exists? true
> Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle11645302661581564201.bin offset 628139 exists? true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally 5 hours of research I got solution of this,

1. I changed project level build.gradle

   ```
     dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' //old gradle
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3' //new gradle
        }
   ```
2. after that change gradle-wrapper.properties which is located in yourprojectPath/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
   change last line

   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip //old url
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip // new url